# Java number precision in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, math, numbers

I have the following code in Java that convert Hex values to Long numbers, in the example I used the value: 'B4EEB49B04C0'

```
public static long HexStr2Long(String value)
{
    value = value.toUpperCase();
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
    {
        int x = value.length() - i - 1;
        char ch = value.charAt(i);
        result += keys.indexOf(ch) * Pow(exponent, x);
    }
    return result;
}

public static long Pow(long baseNo, long x)
{
    long value = 1;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        value = value * baseNo;
        x--;
    }
    return value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = HexStr2Long("B4EEB49B04C0");
    System.out.print("resultado: "+result+"\n");
}
```

The result is: 1463925582232863984

Now, I created the equivalent code in Javascript:

```
pow = function(baseNo, x){
  var value = 1;
  while(x > 0){
    value = value * baseNo;
    x--;
  }

  return value;
}

hexStr2Long = function(val){
 var keys = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 var exponent = keys.length;

 val = val.toUpperCase();
 var result = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    var x = val.length - i - 1;
    var ch = val.charAt(i);
    result +=  keys.indexOf(ch) * Math.pow(exponent, x);
 }

 return result;
}
var r = hexStr2Long(wifimac);
console.log('Result: '+r);
```

The result is: 1463925582232864000, this in wrong, it has to be the same as Java code.

How can I accomplish that? I've already tried to use the library ([BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)) but without success.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you are not calling the pow function that you defined, you are calling Math.pow instead

Comment: Yes, I know that. The result is the same anyway.

Comment: @Andreas I ran into the same fault in my (wrong) answer below. If you interpret the hex number as IEEE-754 FP number, it yields exactly 1463925582232863984.

Answer (score 2):

1463925582232864000 is the nearest 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number to 1463925582232863984. Numbers in Javascript are (at the moment - I believe this is changing) always 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point numbers.

Basically, in order to do this you'll need a Javascript library that supports numeric types *other* than what's built in. (I'd expect BigNumber to work, but you haven't shown us what you tried with it, so it's hard to know what you did wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some info into why:
https://modernweb.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-points/

The problem is with Javascript's floating point precision.

You could always try another library like Math.js

Comment: You will have to configure math.js to use BigNumbers or Fractions of course, by default it still uses regular JS numbers.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I saw that 0xB4EEB49B04C0 is in IEEE-754 FP hexadecimal representation. So this answer is not appropriate at all.

1463925582232863984 is the correct decimal representation for the input!

Accordingly you should use a bignumber library that supports IEEE-754 input.

IGNORE old answer

Using BigNumber works as expected:

```
var r2 = new BigNumber("B4EEB49B04C0", 16);
console.log(r2.toString());
```

It outputs 198937325274304. Also online bignumber converters give this result.
That tends me to suspect that the output of your Java code is wrong too. Can you verify that "1463925582232863984" is the correct result?

The input is a 48-bit number, so it cannot be greater as the maximum supported 64 bit number. Your posted result should equal "1450e88f9298c4f0" as input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank. The result "1463925582232863984" is correct. The Java code is from a company of GPS, they give me that code to convert Mac Address to numbers, since I'm using NodeJS, I want to convert the Java code in Javascript.

Comment: The maximum supported integer is 9007199254740991 which is apparently less than your result value. But your input fits into 48 bit, so the result cannot be larger than MAX_INT imo.

Comment: @FrankSchmid: No, there are supported integer values much, much larger than that. 9007199254740991 (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) is just the maximum integer you can add 1 to and get the next consecutive integer.