# Binary to Decimal conversion showing wrong result for large number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert below binary(64 bit) number to decimal number
'1000000010000001000011111111100100010110011001011001110111000111'

but it is showing the wrong result. I am using below function to convert the number.

```
binaryToDecimal(binaryVal) {
    let val = 0,
      finalVal = 0,
      binaryArray = binaryVal.split('');

    for (let index = 0; index < binaryArray.length; index++) {
      if(Number(binaryArray[index])){
        val = Math.pow(2, binaryArray.length - (index + 1));
      }
      finalVal = finalVal + val;
      val = 0;
    }
    return finalVal;
  }
```

The value I am getting: 9259699871347483000
the correct result will be: 9259699871347482055

please suggest if it is possible in JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the value is correct, check builtin conversion `parseInt('1000000010000001000011111111100100010110011001011001110111000111', 2)`

Comment: @jcubic it is not working it is showing result 9259699871347483000 but the correct value should be 9259699871347482055

Comment: Then it's probably to big number, try to use BigInt, there are also libraries if you need to support browser that don't have that type. In my code I use bn.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java number precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052667/java-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for reducing.

```js
var factor = BigInt(2),
    binary = '1000000010000001000011111111100100010110011001011001110111000111',
    decimal = Array
        .from(binary, BigInt)
        .reduce((r, b) => r * factor + b, BigInt(0));
    

console.log(decimal.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a very compact solution to your problem just add `0b` infront of your number and then return as a `BigInt`

```
function binaryToDecimal(binaryVal) {
   return BigInt(`0b${binaryVal}`)
}
```

Comment: Nice, even compacter `return BigInt(\`0b${binaryVal}\`)`